# Asynchoronous action calls with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm looking into microsoft's version of MVC as a framework for a site redesign that I'm about to begin.

I am not totally new to MVC, I worked on a java app using MVC. We used the DOJO javascript library to make asynchronous calls back to the actions to update views.

What are some of my choices to do the same in .net MVC?

I'd like an excuse to get my hands dirty with jQuery, is this a good one?

Comment: Sounds like a good fit to me.  I don't have much experience with Ajax yet, but I do know that you can do it with ASP.NET MVC and jQuery, and it is clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery is definitely useful for this. If you or your company has any 3rd party control such as the Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET you can give those a try too. I think they are free for beta right now.

However, the best starting point is always looking at code that already exists. There are also tons of examples of AJAX with MVC all over the net.

[Nikhil Kothari's Example](http://www.nikhilk.net/Ajax-MVC.aspx)

[David Hayden's Example 1](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/05/19/ASPNETMVCAjaxBeginForm.aspx)

[David Hayden's Example 2](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/06/17/AspNetMvcAjaxHelpersScreencast.aspx)

[Scott Hanselman's Example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCPreview4UsingAjaxAndAjaxForm.aspx)

Go download the [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) example that ScottGu, ScottHa etc. worked on for their book.

Comment: To clarify, the Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC are free and open source (and they are also built on jQuery on the client). Online demos and downloads are available: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is one of the most widely used javascript frameworks used with ASP.Net MVC, also check out ExtJs. We use ExtJs at work and I think its been documented well and its very easy to use. The jQuery community is a lot bigger though so I would say its a safer bet

Answer (score 1):

Sure you should go with JQuery..You have already experience in MVC, I think you will not take much time to understand JQuery.

http://visualjquery.com/